# segfault at strcmp - possibly issue passing pointer from struct

Tags: c

I am attempting to compare a user inputted search term with a number of names in a linked list. I know for sure that it is segfaulting at strcmp but none of the solutions for segfaults at strcmp seem to be the problem.

Here is my code! I am still very new to StackOverflow & C so I apologize in advance for any dumb mistakes I make in the posting of this or in my actual programming. ><

```
struct node{
char* name;
struct node* next;
};

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char reader;
char srchbuff[1001];
char name[10] = "Justin";
char* srch;
int i;

struct node *head;
struct node *cur;

head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->name = name;
head->next = 0;

for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
   scanf("%c", &reader);
   srchbuff[i] = reader;
}


srchbuff[i] = '\0';
srch = malloc(sizeof(char)*i);
strcpy(srch, srchbuff);

cur = head;

while( (cur != NULL) && (strcmp(cur->name, srch)) != 0){
    cur = cur->next;
}
}
```

There are other nodes allocated in a separate function, that works fine, and the information is also allocated in a separate function (it also works fine), and my struct is in my header file so it's all happy and recognized.

I have also tested with gdb and printf statements to make sure the strcmp is where I'm segfaulting, and it definitely is. Thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: Can you give us a minimal working example that compiles but exhibits the bug you describe?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by working example - like the .in file I'm testing from?

Comment: Hey Austin - just for future reference (for new and old C developers alike), there is a class of tools called 'static source analysis' tools that would catch bugs like this. Splint is the name of such a tool. It's under the GPL, so you don't have to buy it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splint_%28programming_tool%29

Comment: @Austin A working example is a full program compilable by people who want to help you that exhibits the bug you're talking about. It is much more work to reassemble a program from the fragments you give us and hope that it really has the bug you're showing us.

Comment: @FUZxxl oh! I'm sorry, I just added that >_<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the line

```
srchbuff[i] = '\0';
```

you write one byte beyond the end of srchbuff.

The memory `srch` points to, is not initialized. So anything might happen.

`cur` is also not initialized. This means `cur` points anywhere and so does `cur->name`.

Comment: altered srchbuff to be an array of size 1001, and am now writing to srchbuff[i+1] for that.

added a for loop making the items in srch = the corresponding items in srchbuff.

also initialized cur = head. However, still segfaulting >_<

Comment: 1. Only increase `srchbuff` to 1001. Don't do `i+1`! 2. Instead of a loop use `strcpy()`. Show your modifications in the question.

Comment: okay, made those changes and reflected them in the question! Thanks for being so patient :)

Comment: @AustinLeigh No problem. The code looks fine so far. Incorporate @Hristo's suggestion too and initialize the `head` node to a meaningful value. Then you're set.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using uninitialised memory in `srch`, you have no condition to stop the loop at the end of the list. You should modify it to something like this:

```
while (cur != NULL && strcmp(cur->name, srch) != 0){
   cur = cur->next;
}
```

Otherwise at the end of the list, `cur` would become `NULL` and null pointer dereference would occur at `cur->name` on the next iteration.